# Nginx Ingress + nextjs -> 404

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I have many services operating happily behind an `Nginx Ingress on EKS` for some time. Recently I've been trying to deploy a `next.js` app behind this Ingress but I can't get it to work.

The only solutions I can find online seem to be adding various header as an annotation in the `ingress.yaml` but these have no effect. I can't get passed the `404`. A blank page is loaded as `next.js` can't load the files it needs.

The `404` stems from `next.js` rather than `Nginx`, so the request is still at least reaching the container. The app works correctly when run locally using Docker.

I've tried variations of the config below with no success. Not sure if the rewrite is interfering with things, but doesn't seem to be.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$3
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
        location /app {
        #proxy_pass ; Is this needed in an Ingress?
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        }

  labels:
    app: app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          # Any path containing "file"
          - path: /(/|$)(((.*).*(file).*))
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: file-api
                port:
                  number: 80

          - path: /app
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: nextjs-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Am I using the wrong values in the annotation or is my approach wrong entirely?